# Java Date validation

Tags: java, date

i need to validate user input as valid date. User can enter dd/mm/yyyy or mm/yyyy (both are valid)

to validate this i was doing

```
try{
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); 
    cal.setLenient(false);  
    String []userDate = uDate.split("/");
    if(userDate.length == 3){
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(userDate[2]));  
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(userDate[1]));  
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(userDate[0]));
        cal.getTime(); 
    }else if(userDate.length == 2){
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(userDate[1]));  
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(userDate[0]));  
        cal.getTime(); 
    }else{
            // invalid date
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    //Invalid date
}
```

as GregorianCalendar start month with 0, 30/01/2009 or 12/2009 gives error.

any suggestion how to solve this issue.

Comment: how is `mm/yyyy` a sufficient format for you to validate it?

Comment: user can only provide valid month and year only. not day of month. so mm/yyyy is also valid in this case.

Comment: If  this app. has a GUI, an obvious answer is to offer the user a date chooser that only has valid dates (e.g. no weekends or public holidays) selectable.

Comment: `cal.getTime()` doesn't do anything by itself.  You have to use the result of that expression.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10):

Use `SimpleDateformat`. If the parsing failes it throws a `ParseException`:

```
private Date getDate(String text) throws java.text.ParseException {

    try {
        // try the day format first
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        df.setLenient(false);

        return df.parse(text);
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        // fall back on the month format
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
        df.setLenient(false);

        return df.parse(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree you should use SimpleDateFormat, but your example is incomplete: without call 'setLenient(false)' on the SimpleDateFormat it will accept invalid input and turn it into nonsensical dates. Also, you need to catch the exception thrown by the first parse() before trying the second format.

Comment: @Arnout: Good point, I was already updating while you wrote your comment... :)

Comment: @sn s: The separator character is `/` if you want `.` you need to provide the format string as `"dd.mm.yyyy"` but that won't work for example `"07/01/2001`".

Comment: @dacwe it accept 25.45.2001 as valid date. any idea why it does not give exception

Comment: @sn s: Updated (`MM` instead of `mm`)!

Comment: After using setLenient(false), still treating '2013-04-22ab' as valid.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to validate `Date` and [`setLenient`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use a [`try - catch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) to trap [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) thrown from [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) and [`YearMonth.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) in the *java.time* classes.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

### `YearMonth`

For only a year-month without a day-of-month, use the `YearMonth` class.

If possible, have your users use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for data entry: `YYYY-MM`. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "2018-01" ) ;
```

If not possible, specify a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uuuu" ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "01/2018" , f ) ;
```

To test for invalid input, trap for an exception.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uuuu" ) ;
YearMonth ym = null ;
try{
    ym = YearMonth.parse( "01/2018" , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    // Handle faulty input
    …
}
```

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use `LocalDate` class.

Again, use standard ISO 8601 format for data-entry if possible: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ;
```

If not, specify a formatting pattern and trap for exception as seen above.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = null ;
try{
    ld = LocalDate.parse( "23/01/2018" , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    // Handle faulty input
    …
}
```

## Combining

If the input may be either a date-only or a year-month, then test the length of input to determine which is which.

```
int length = input.length() ;
switch ( length ) {
    case 7 :
        …  // Process as year-month using code seen above.

    case 10 :
        …  // Process as date-only using code seen above.

    default: 
        …  // ERROR, unexpected input.
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).