# How do I validate a date using split method of String?

Tags: java, string, validation, date, split

How do I validate a date(i mean that the date should not be invalid) using  split method of string class?
Further details: Each month should have their respective days and February should have 29 days only when it is a leap year and date should not exceed the present date.

Comment: Are you receiving dates as strings? and if so what's the format of the date written as?

Comment: and what have tried so far?

Comment: Uhm, you _are_ aware that the JDK has classes to parse dates already? (`SimpleDateFormat` in this case)

Comment: You can use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Why do you want not to use DateFormat.parse()?

Comment: @fge & Leos Looks like we all are on the same page

Comment: thx all.Can anyone give me the code or an example that i enter date in a string and that gets validated(by any technique)??

Comment: three same comments within 2 seconds range :-)

Comment: @user3364497 this depends on the initial format of your date to begin with

Comment: @fge:i am using string as the initial format

Comment: @user3364497 3/19/20, 03-19-20, 2007, Feb. 19, etc. There's no way to tell how you should exactly split your date. But I'm guessing you would want to eliminate any commas, slashes, etc. and then retrieve only the number values for month, day, and year. Then process that, assuming you're going to use a Gregorian calendar, to determine whether it's a valid date. Oh and you'd have to take into account of leap years, but of course that would be part of the process of determining if that is a valid date or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332268/java-date-validation)

Answer (score 2):

I can recomment to use validate(String value) method from [Apache Commons DateValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DateValidator.html#validate%28java.lang.String%29):

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DateValidator;
...

// Get the Date validator
DateValidator validator = DateValidator.getInstance();

// Validate/Convert the date
Date fooDate = validator.validate(fooString);
if (fooDate == null) {
    // error...not a valid date
    return;
}
```

*validate()* returns parsed Date if valid or null if invalid.

If you want only to get true/false, then there is another boolean method *isValid()*. For example:

```
DateValidator validator = DateValidator.getInstance();
if (validator.isValid(date)) {
    System.out.println(date + " is valid");
} else {
    System.out.println(date + " is invalid");
}
```

Comment: and bro how i incorporate this into java?? i have no idea about apache.

Comment: @user3364497 see the javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`; it is integrated into Java itself. What is more, a better library to handle time is Joda Time, if you want to use an external lib, use this one rather than Apache's

Comment: dude i know this, but i don't have the package.

Comment: Declare that import and download the commons-validator-1.4.0-bin.zip from mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org//commons/validator/binaries/commons-validator-1.4.0-bin.zip. Then extract it and add commons-validator-1.4.0.jar to your build path.

Answer (score 1):

In the JDK, you have [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to handle this kind of stuff.

For instance, to validate an hour:

```
final DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Then you can try and parse:

```
fmt.parse(input);
```

It will throw a [`ParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) if the date is invalid.

Of course, many other formats can be done.

As to external libraries, if you have to/want to use one, there is really only one to consider: [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It is so good a library that Java 8's new date API is 90+% inspired by it.

NOTE: JDK's as well as Joda Time's, parsers will derive missing components in a date from the current time; it means that if you try and parse a string containing `Feb 29` in 2015, it will fail... But it will succeed in 2016 since it is a leap year!

Comment: nice one and best approach.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat will produce wrong results, try, for example, with String date = "32/02/2014";

Answer (score 0):

```
convert string to date format, and this is easy for validating 

public class DateUtil {

    // List of all date formats that we want to parse.
    // Add your own format here.
//u can use anyone format
    private static List<SimpleDateFormat>; 
            dateFormats = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>() {{
            add(new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy"));
            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy"));
            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy"));
            add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        }
    };

    /**
     * Convert String with various formats into java.util.Date
     * 
     * @param input
     *            Date as a string
     * @return java.util.Date object if input string is parsed 
     *          successfully else returns null
     */
    public static Date convertToDate(String input) {
        Date date = null;
        if(null == input) {
            return null;
        }
        for (SimpleDateFormat format : dateFormats) {
            try {
                format.setLenient(false);
                date = format.parse(input);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //Shhh.. try other formats
            }
            if (date != null) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, in your `try` block you can just `return format.parse(input);` ;)

Comment: if it is 'Catch' means data is invalid and set return boolean value.its simple @fge

Comment: I am not talking about `catch` here but about your `try` block. If you do as I say, you don't even need to check for `null` after the `catch`, and you don't even need the `date` variable to begin with

Comment: yes i agree with you @fge,yours is simple,but,,my example provided different formats for user convenience.