# How to check a date input by user to see if correct format in java?

Tags: java, arrays, date, compare

Basically as you can see from the code, I want the user to enter a date, (start date & end date) but I want to make sure that the system doesn't let he user type in something else. and the user should be able to type it again. Where am I going wrong?

```
    System.out.println("Enter your date here: "); 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    UserInput = scan.nextLine();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(UserInput);

    while (true) {
        if (!isValidDate(date)){
            System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
            break;
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("That is not a valid date! Please enter again (dd-mm-yy): ");
        UserInput = scan.nextLine();
        break;
        }
    } 
private static boolean isValidDate(Date date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

and also if I will finally manage to do this? how can I add it an array saved in another class? 
my array are like this

```
arrayUsers[0] = new User("User", "One", 1234, 1234, 0); 
arrayUsers[1] = new User("User2", "Two" , 4321, 4321, 0);
```

I would like to add these "start date & date" here, but after 0 at the end of array.
Thanks

Comment: what is in isValidDate ?

Comment: what is this isValidDate? check if this return true when date is valid or otherwise. Also you should use dateFormat.setLenient(false), it will give you parse exception if invalid date is entered.

Comment: By default, if the user enters invalid date, then parse method will throw ParseException. IMO, you handle that exception with appropriate message. Your title says about date comparison but your actual question is different.

Comment: It didn't work at the beginning, and it came up with an error. Then when I went to fix it it added a method at the bottom and it's empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332268/java-date-validation)

Comment: @BasilBourque It is nothing like the one you just showed me. I cant see where the user types a date in, and using throw ParseException it doesn't work, because that's how i'm trying to do it and i do have that. The reason i posted this is because i didn't find an answer anywhere else.